# Show text data in div

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on the C# ASP.Net MVC project. I use Entity Framework for crud stuff. I am trying to show a text from my database in a div but not list type. I want to manage my index page content and title. I can do crud stuff but I don't know how can I show data in a div can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to add c# code in Html tags
don't forget to use the @ for c#

```html
<div>
      <p>@user.FirstName</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Home Index page, you'll need to pass in a model in order to reference the data you want passed from the Home controller Index method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).